# Save power while uploading YouTube video

Tags: power-management, youtube, powersave

I have a really slow connection with no way of upgrading (already got the fastest available speed for the area) and large video files that I wish to upload to YouTube. I have no way of utilizing the computer throughout the upload process (renders are faster than uploads). So the computer is practically idling for many hours at the time, or overnight often.

Any way to save power during the upload process? Can I somehow automate the process or have the PC running at a low power mode during this?

Comment: Have you tried to schedule a task that changes your power plan.

Comment: You'll have to determine what processes and resources that power saving can apply to are necessary vs unnecessary for uploading your data, and then apply appropriate settings. A simple thing would be to set processor scaling, and turning off your screen. Beyond that is it difficult to say.

Comment: Already took these steps. Was wondering if there's more to do.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't say *why* you wanted to reduce power consumption.

If you are looking to save money, you aren't going to be saving much, depending on your region. Let's assume in the United States. Let's also assume you have a super-beefy power supply, say 1000 Watts. Running your machine at full power for an hour will cost an average of $0.11. That's not much.

Comment: I live on Greece where electricity is presumably more expensive. I have a 650 Watt power supply with a 80+ efficiency rating and a i5 4430 under the hood. My main concern is to save money as well as prolong the life of my hardware. That's because videos take a long time to upload, and I am rendering videos regularly which have my pc running at 100% for many hours at the time.

Answer (score 0):

Your computer/os should largely do this for you - particularly if its a modern Intel CPU.  You can probably tweek it using power management settings and turning off the monitor/dimming the screen and disabling fancy screensavers.  Changing CPU scaling and reducing frequencies can help as well here.

Also maybe you can script the uploads and turn off/hibernate the system once its done.

If you want something with more significant powersavings (or if you have an old PC) , maybe rig a Raspberry Pi box up as a NAS and do the upload from that instead of your main PC.

( @keltari certainly has a point about doing a cost benefit analysis. Assuming a more realistic 250 watt draw including cooling, at 11c / kwh and 8 hour night you would be paying about US$6.70 per month, so you would be looking at a multi year payback on any hardware, ignoring the hassle/multistep costs. Ofcourse if you are paying $0.50 per kwh from a generator/off grid system the numbers may stack up differently. )